# Beautiful Soup: Parsing between commas in unicode list into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode, beautifulsoup

I scraping a list of names and dates. I can get the data into a unicode LIST,
then im pretty much having trouble with everything else.

A sample output of my soup object:

```
LAST,FIRST,ID,DEBUT
Aardsma,David,aardd001,04/06/2004
Aaron,Hank,aaroh101,04/13/1954
Aaron,Tommie,aarot101,04/10/1962
```

First I want to strip the first line: 'LAST,FIRST,ID,DEBUT',but pop(0) doesnt work on a unicode list.

Next I want to parse the names, etc into 4 columns and put it into a pandas dataframe.

Here is my latest code that needs a lot of work:

```
import urllib2
import csv
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Cols=['Last','First','ID','Debut']
sock= urllib2.urlopen('http://www.retrosheet.org/retroID.htm')
link=sock.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(link,'lxml')


list=soup.find_all('pre')
for td in list:
    IDList=td.get_text()


df=pd.DataFrame(IDList,columns=Cols) # giving error so far
print(df)   
#IDList=IDList.split(",")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is already csv formatted so all you need to do is dump into a StringIO and have pandas read it.

I don't have python3 around to verify and StringIO has changed between python 2 and python 3-- so playing the StringIO piece by memory a bit.  But off the top of my head I believe this would work in either.

```
import urllib2
import csv
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except:
    from io import StringIO

Cols=['Last','First','ID','Debut']
sock= urllib2.urlopen('http://www.retrosheet.org/retroID.htm')
link=sock.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(link,'lxml')

csv_data = StringIO(soup.find('pre').text)
df = pd.read_csv(csv_data)
print(df)
```